# phpmyadmin sso doesn't remove existing session in logout

Tags: php, session, yii, phpmyadmin, single-sign-on

I'm trying to use PHPMyAdmin SSO in my custom application, made in Yii framework. Following phpMyAdmin guide I've made the needed changes in config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'MYSESSID';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL'] = 'http://myapp.com/site/login';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LogoutURL'] = 'http://myapp.com/site/logout';
```

PHPMyAdmin is linked to http://myapp.com/phpmyadmin/ and in my application when someone logins I set the *PMA_single_signon_user* and *PMA_single_signon_password* with the username and password values. In the logout action I destroy the session (Yii::app()->session->destroy() equivelant to session_unset();session_destroy()).

When a user logs into the application successfully he can click the phpmyadmin link and he'll be redirected successfully to the phpmyadmin interface.

When a user logsout of the application, doesn't close the browser and logs in again my phpmyadmin link is redirecting to the login (SignonURL), even though the user was successfully logged in.

Using firebug and some var_dumps in phpmyadmin/libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationSignon.class.php I've noticed that after a logout phpmyadmin still uses a MYSESSID under path /phpmyadmin/ which has the previous session's value.

For example, I login to the myapp.com/site/login and I get

```
MYSESSID="value1" path=/
```

and i successfully click the myapp.com/phpmyadmin/ link. Now I have two MYSESSID in the br

```
MYSESSID="value1" path=/ 
MYSESSID="value1" path=/phpmyadmin/
```

I logout (not closing the browser window) and login again, getting a new value in MYSESSID like:

```
MYSESSID="value2" path=/
```

I click the myapp.com/phpmyadmin/ link (I exit before the redirection to SingonURL) and see these sessions:

```
MYSESSID="value2" path=/ 
MYSESSID="value1" path=/phpmyadmin/
```

From the AuthenticationSignon.class.php I understand that since phpmyadmin searches inside MYSESSID="value1" it can't find the needed *PMA_single_signon_user* and *PMA_single_signon_password*
since I placed them under MYSESSID="value2".

Bottom line of what I've understood is that when i destroy the session during the logout the session defined under path=/phpmyadmin/ is not being removed.

anyone has any idea on how to properly logout or remove the session under path=/phpmyadmin/ ?

When I close the browser window the MysESSID="value1" is completely removed for both paths / and /phpmyadmin/ so the re-login works fine.

Note: I use only myapp.com and no www.myapp.com at all

Comment: I can't post an answer yet, so i'm writting it inside the comment.

It seems that the way to remove the session under /phpmyadmin/ path is to do a 

    setcookie("WPCPSESSID", $_COOKIE["MYSESSID"],time()-100, '/phpmyadmin/');

inside the logout action, actually create a new cookie with a past expire time. This way the session expires without having to close the window. The session_unset();session_destroy(); removes the cookies under "/" path only.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to explicitly set a session cookie with a past time (thus already expired)

```
setcookie("WPCPSESSID", $_COOKIE["MYSESSID"],time()-100, '/phpmyadmin/');
```

This way the phpmyadmin session expires without having to close the window.

It seems that  session_unset();session_destroy(); removes the session cookie under "/" path only and not from subpages (e.g. /phpmyadmin/)